# Shortcut to open gmail label directly from another android program

Tags: android, gmail

I have a problem, and I am aware is not fully supported by Android.

I am looking for a way to open specific Gmail labels directly from another Android application.

So, in the Android app I want to be able to get the email count for a Gmail label.

However, based on research, I have observed that accessing custom (user-defined) labels is not so straight forward. Any help will be much appreciated.

Summary Question: How can I directly access (open) user-defined Gmail labels from an Android application and determine the number of unread emails in that label.

Might there be something available that is similar to the Gmail Label notifier application?

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of Gmail support a `ContentProvider` which, I think, gives you what you want. You can read more on the [Android Gmail developer site](https://developers.google.com/gmail/android/).

Note, again, that this will only work on newer versions of Gmail. You might consider using `PackageManager` to confirm the existence of the `ContentProvider` in question on any given device.